# Extreme slow update SQL with image in Java

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a database of 70,000 records. For each record in the database I have to put images in PNG format. I need to loop and update all the records.

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dbServer + ";databaseName=" + dbName + ";user=" + dbUser + ";password=" + dbPassword + "";
Connection link = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement stmt = link.createStatement();

ResultSet row = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM postal_codes");

while(row.next()){
  File imageFile = new File("C:\\res\\flags\\" + filename + ".png");
  String query = "UPDATE postal_codes SET flag = ? ........... WHERE ID = ?";
  PreparedStatement preStmt = link.prepareStatement(query);
  preStmt.setBinaryStream(1, new FileInputStream(imageFile), (int)imageFile.length());
  preStmt.setInt(10, row.getInt("ID"));
  preStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

I executed this script and it's already 14 minutes of execution and the loop is at a 30,000 record!

I have an identically working script in PHP and Python. In those languages, the script takes up to ~300 seconds to finish all records.

What am I doing wrong?

PHP ~ 280 seconds

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $fileData = file_get_contents('res/flags/'.$filename.'.png');
  $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE postal_codes SET flag = :flag ......... WHERE ID = '.$row['ID'].'');
  $stmt->bindParam(':flag', $fileData, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Python ~ 190 seconds

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  image = open('../res/flags/' + filename + '.png', 'rb')
  image_data = image.read()
  image.close()
  cursor.execute("UPDATE postal_codes SET flag = ? ....... WHERE ID = ?", image_data, row.ID)
  conn.commit()
```

The value under the variable "filename" may be different. That's why I have to loop all records.

Comment: You could look into batch updates. [JDBC Developer's Guide: Performance Extensions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/performance-extensions.html#GUID-FEECA64F-44F4-453F-B8A8-AFBF6D29ABA4).

Comment: You don't have to call `prepareStatement()` in a loop. Just do it once, before the loop, and re-use the prepared statement.

Comment: `new FileInputStream(imageFile)` might be inefficient.  Normally we wrap a stream in a `BufferedInputStream`.  In addition, the regular IO is a bit slow (on purpose, it tries to conserve resources).  For better performance look at NIO.

Comment: Is this even legal, doing an update while pulling a select on the same connection? You could do this much simpler with a single joined `update` statement

Comment: Id it all executed on the server/client side?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare the statement outside the loop and, most importantly, use a transaction instead of committing after each row, because "By default, new connections are in autocommit mode." -- [setAutocommit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/setautocommit-method-sqlserverconnection?view=sql-server-ver15)